# MySQL Stored Procedures issue with if then else statements

Tags: mysql, procedures

I have the need to store the changes in our invoice system to export it to the account system (which is a 3rd party app).

What I'm trying to do is to add two triggers.

1. ON INSERT : A new invoice is added, it has to be marked as new in another table, so in the next migration, generate the appropiate ASCII to import it in the accounting system.
2. ON UPDATE: This is a bit more complicated, this can happen when an invoice is modified or when an invoice becomes payed / or it was marked to be payed and finally it hasnt.

Both Triggers call the same procedure.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `marca_factura_modificada`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE `marca_factura_modificada`( IN nempresa_in int, IN nfactura_in int, IN cany_in char(2), IN cobrada boolean  )
BEGIN
    DECLARE existeix_factura INT;
    DECLARE abans_afegir_factura INT;
    DECLARE abans_afegir_cobrament INT;

    SELECT NFactura,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament 
               INTO existeix_factura,abans_afegir_factura,abans_afegir_cobrament 
               FROM factures_modificades 
               WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in 
                     AND NFactura = nfactura_in 
                     AND CAny = cany_in 
                     LIMIT 1;
    IF existeix_factura IS NULL THEN
        IF new.DataFactura = CURDATE() THEN
            IF (new.LComptat = 1 OR new.LCreditCobrat = 1) THEN
                INSERT INTO factures_modificades (NEmpresa, NFactura, CAny,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament ) 
                    VALUES (nempresa_in, nfactura_in, cany_in,1,1);
            ELSE
                INSERT INTO factures_modificades (NEmpresa, NFactura, CAny,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament ) 
                    VALUES (nempresa_in, nfactura_in, cany_in,1,0);
            END IF
        ELSE
            /* Si no és d'avui i no hi ha registre es que ja es va afegir la factura en el seu dia */
            INSERT INTO factures_modificades (NEmpresa, NFactura, CAny,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament ) 
            VALUES (nempresa_in, nfactura_in, cany_in,0,1);
        END IF
    ELSE
        IF(cobrada = 0 AND abans_afegir_factura = 0) THEN
            DELETE FROM factures_modificades WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in AND NFactura = nfactura_in AND CAny = cany_in LIMIT 1;
        ELSEIF (cobrada = 1 AND abans_afegir_cobrament = 0) THEN
            UPDATE factures_modificades SET afegir_cobrament =  1 WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in AND NFactura = nfactura_in AND CAny = cany_in;
        ELSEIF (cobrada = 0 AND abans_afegir_cobrament = 1) THEN
            UPDATE factures_modificades SET afegir_cobrament = 0 WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in AND NFactura = nfactura_in AND CAny = cany_in;
        END IF
    END IF
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

But this doesnt work on mysql 5.5 (I think there is some issue in IF THEN ELSE code, but I dont see where.

Comment: This is a complicated question.  There are many, many ways that a stored procedure can "not work".  Please elaborate on what the problem is that you are having.

Comment: The problem appears in the "INSERT INTO factures_modificades (NEmpresa, NFactura, CAny,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament )  VALUES (nempresa_in, nfactura_in, cany_in,0,1);" this one its after the second else. I dunno, but I think that which is bad is the IF THEN ELSE statements... Is there a way to separate them? I mean like in php  if (something){ some_stuff(); }else if(something_else) {that();} else { another_stuff();}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved!

Now it works. The problem was END IF wants a ; in the end.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `marca_factura_modificada`;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE `marca_factura_modificada`( IN nempresa_in int, IN nfactura_in int, IN cany_in char(2), IN cobrada boolean,IN DataFactura date  )
BEGIN
    DECLARE existeix_factura INT;
    DECLARE abans_afegir_factura INT;
    DECLARE abans_afegir_cobrament INT;
    SELECT NFactura,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament 
               INTO existeix_factura,abans_afegir_factura,abans_afegir_cobrament 
               FROM factures_modificades 
               WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in 
                     AND NFactura = nfactura_in 
                     AND CAny = cany_in 
                     LIMIT 1;
    IF (existeix_factura) IS NULL THEN 
            IF (DataFactura = CURDATE()) THEN 
                IF (cobrada) THEN INSERT INTO factures_modificades (NEmpresa, NFactura, CAny,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament ) VALUES (nempresa_in, nfactura_in, cany_in,1,1);
                ELSE INSERT INTO factures_modificades (NEmpresa, NFactura, CAny,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament ) VALUES (nempresa_in, nfactura_in, cany_in,1,0);
                END IF;
            ELSE INSERT INTO factures_modificades (NEmpresa, NFactura, CAny,afegir_factura,afegir_cobrament )  VALUES (nempresa_in, nfactura_in, cany_in,0,1);
            END IF;
    ELSE
        IF(cobrada = 0 AND abans_afegir_factura = 0) THEN DELETE FROM factures_modificades WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in AND NFactura = nfactura_in AND CAny = cany_in LIMIT 1;
        ELSEIF (cobrada = 1 AND abans_afegir_cobrament = 0) THEN UPDATE factures_modificades SET afegir_cobrament =  1 WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in AND NFactura = nfactura_in AND CAny = cany_in;
        ELSEIF (cobrada = 0 AND abans_afegir_cobrament = 1) THEN UPDATE factures_modificades SET afegir_cobrament = 0 WHERE NEmpresa = nempresa_in AND NFactura = nfactura_in AND CAny = cany_in;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```